# United States Italian Embassy Visa Appointment Question

Tags: schengen, international-travel, schengen-visas, italy

I am applying for a Schengen visa to Italy from the United States (US green card holder). I was finally able to book an appointment with the Italian Embassy in Los Angeles using their booking system, Prenot@mi. However, in the rush of trying to secure the appointment my passport number was input incorrectly, off by one number. I also used my married name vs. maiden name on the Prenot@mi website.

The question: Will either of these cause issues when I show up for my appointment? All my forms and documents I intend to actually apply with are correct, its just the appointment system details that are slightly off.

Comment: I would suggest logging in to your account at the Prenot@mi website and adapt everthing to match the passport that you will be travelling with. The appointment is probably linked to that account. If the passport number cannot be changed, inform them when the appointment starts that you misstyped the passport number. When going to your appointment, look for [Consulate General of Italy in Los Angeles](https://conslosangeles.esteri.it/consolato_losangeles/en/), since the Italian Embassy is in Washington DC.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I would change on Prenotami, but the website does not allow me to change last name nor passport information.

Comment: Were you able to get the appointment for Schengen visa easily. I have been trying for a week and it just says no appointment available.

Comment: @dilbaghsingh I'd really suggest you look at 23:15 **Italian Time**, Prenot@mi opens new appointments every day at that time. (Which makes every embassy site extremely overcrowded)